# Link against a map file using ld

Tags: c, gcc, linker

Lets say I have `a.c` and `b.c` sources. Code in `b.c` calls `a.c`, but `a.c` never directly calls any functions from `b.c`. The file `a.c` contains main function.

I compile both of them, and get two object files: `a.o` and `b.o`. I can link only `a.o` and get an executable, producing a `map file`. This `linker map` contains the absolute addresses of all functions in `a.c`.

Now I want to link `b.o` as well. I could give linker both `a.o` and `b.o` and it would work perfectly. But since `a` doesn't call `b`, linking `b.o` doesn't actually need the contents of `a`, only the final addresses of each function inside `a`. Therefore, it should be possible to link `b.o` given only the `map file` that was produced while linking `a.o`.

However, I did not find any appropriate flags to tell `ld` that it should take symbol addresses for a from a map file. **How can I tell `ld` to do that?**

I have found mentions online to people using map files, but never an explanation as to how it was achieved using `ld`. For example from one research paper:

> When  compiling  the Contiki system core, the compiler generated a map file containing the mapping between all globally visible functions and variables in the system core and their addresses.  This list of addresses was used to pre-link Contiki modules.

Comment: What platform (OS, processor) are you interested in?

Comment: @EmployedRussian I am targeting arm-none, but tbh i don't think it should matter, as this concerns the construction of the binary file, and shouldn't introduce any external dependencies either way?